# Having trouble updating specific field in AnuglarFire2

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic4, angularfire2

I have a prize pool in firebase and I would like to update the value by 1 when a user clicks a button, but its been a headache trying to retrieve the correct information and update it. The method I am going for is to read the correct collection, than document, than field. Pull the value of that field, which I am calling amount, and increment it. Than update that amount field with the correct information.

I have tried using update and set on both the reference and myPrize, but I think the way I am pulling data is incorrect for those calls?

```
 async addPrize(dPrice: number){
  let reference = this._db.collection('prizes', ref => ref.where('name', '==', "prize1"));
  let myPrize: Observable<{}> = reference.valueChanges();

  myPrize.subscribe(res=>{
    console.log(res);
    console.log(res[0]['amount'])
  })

}
```